# How I can set Japanese language at VS Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

While coding with Japanese and showing results on screen, it seems to change to Simplify or Traditional Chinese. How can I set it to display in Japanese?
Original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main (void)
{
    int a[5] = {100,200,300,400,500};
    int ban, suu;
    printf("商品番号:");
    scanf("%d", &ban);
    printf("数量");
    scanf("%d", &suu);
    
    while (suu)
    {
        printf("金額=%d円\n", a[ban]*suu);
        printf("商品番号:");
        scanf("%d", &ban);
        printf("数量:");
        scanf("%d", &suu);
    }
return 0;

}
```

Here written in Japanese, and my PC support Japanese letters (bought in Japan). When showing result, it turns to this:

```
蝠・刀逡ｪ蜿ｷ:1
謨ｰ驥20
城≡鬘・4000蜀・
蝠・刀逡ｪ蜿ｷ:
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you have to install the appropriate language pack on Marketplace.
2. Change the display language using Configure Display Language command.
3. Press ctrl+shift+p and type "display."
4. List of languages is displayed, and the current language is highlighted.
5. Once the language is configured, a restart is required.

Check this [page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in the start of the `main()`:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ja_JP.UTF-8");
```

and also

```
#include <locale.h>
```

at the start of the file.